# $X= \int_0^S e^{(S-s)A} B u(s) ds \Rightarrow X= \int_0^T e^{(T-s)A} B \bar{u}(s) ds$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Consider the ODE system
$$X'(t) = AX(t)+Bu(t)$$
where $X(t) \in R^n, \; A \in R^{n \times n} \text{ and } B \in R^{n \times m}$.
In control theory, we define the **set of states reachable** as
$$A(0,T) = \{ \phi(T,0,0,u(.)) : u \in U \}$$
such that $U=\{\text{all the function integrable in a finite interval}\}, \; u: R \rightarrow R^m$ and
$$\phi(T,0,0,u(.)) = \int_0^T e^{(T-s)A} B u(s) ds$$
It is asked to show that if $0<S<T$, then $A(0,S) \subset A(0,T)$

**My attempt:** In general, I need to show that if we $x$ such that
$$X= \int_0^S e^{(S-s)A} B u(s) ds$$
for some $u \in U$, then there might exist $\bar{u} \in U$ such that
$$ X = \int_0^T e^{(T-s)A} B \bar{u}(s) ds$$
correct? We have that

$$ X \in A(0,S) \iff X = \int_0^S e^{(S-s)A} B u(s) ds $$ 
Using the transformation $T-z = S-s$:
$$ X \in A(0,S) \iff  X = \int_{T-S}^T e^{(T-z)A} B u(z-(T-S)) ds$$

Now, I couldn't find how to fix the limits of integration defining a new function $\bar{u}$ using $u$ such that those limits goes from $0$ to $T$. Any idea? Also, I considered define $\bar{u}$ first, but the change of variables to 'fix' the exponential messed my limits of integration too.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if it's possible to use control term with jump discontinuity, you can take $\overline{u}(t) \equiv u(t)$ for $t \in \lbrack 0, S \rbrack$ and set it equal to $u^\ast$ for $t \in \lbrack S, T \rbrack$ where $u^\ast$ satisfies $AX + Bu^\ast = 0$. The idea behind that is simple: you know how to arrive at $X$ at time $S$, why not use this and make the trajectory stay at this point from $S$ to $T$.

Comment: @Evgeny how can we check that this control $u^* \in U$?

Comment: @Evgeny By the way, good idea! But I am having difficults to write the proof, if you can give a little help. I mean, how can I change the term $e^{(S-s)A}$ to $e^{(T-s)A}$? Or I don't need to do this?

Comment: This is just a property of integrable functions: if something is integrable at $\lbrack 0, S \rbrack$ and at $\lbrack S, T \rbrack$ then it's integrable at $\lbrack 0, T \rbrack$. $\overline{u}(t)$ is integrable at $\lbrack 0, S \rbrack$ because it equals $u(t) \in U$; also it's integrable at $\lbrack S, T \rbrack$ because it's just a constant vector.

Comment: I agree, but this "something" that is integrable at $[0,S]$ has $e^{(S-s)A} $term, but I need $(T-s)$ at the exponential. Also, how can I guarantee thaat $u^*$ exists? As I understood, you said it is a constant, but it would imply that the system has solution. The idea is clear for me, from $t \in [S, T]$, the system stands at $X(S)$, correct? Then, we will have at time $T$ $X(S)$

Comment: 1) I think I have to show some exponent juggling in answer; 2) If $B$ has full rank (i.e., ${\rm rank} B = \min \lbrace n, m \rbrace$) you can be sure that this $u^\ast$ exists; 3) Yes, you've got it right: $X(T) = X(S)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that $A(0, S) = \operatorname{Im} W_r(0, S)$ where

$$ W_r(0, S) := \int_0^S e^{(S-\tau) A} B B^T e^{(S-\tau) A^T} d\tau $$

A very nice proof can be found [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/faculty/j/x/jxl77/courses/ee580_fa10/ee580_note08.pdf). Now you just need to prove that $\operatorname{Im} W_r(0, S) \subseteq \operatorname{Im} W_r(0, T)$, which is pretty easy.

Comment: Since $W_r(0,S) = W_r(0,T) - \int_S^Te^{\tau A} B B^T e^{\tau A^T} d\tau$, if $x=W_r(0,S) \eta$ for some $\eta$, then $x =  W_r(0,T) \eta - \int_S^Te^{\tau A} B B^T e^{\tau A^T} d\tau \; \eta$ shows that $x \in \text{Im} W_r(0,T)$?

Comment: What if we choose $\bar{u}(\tau) = B^Te^{\tau A}\eta$ for $t \in [0,S]$ and $\bar{u}(\tau) = -B^Te^{\tau A}\eta$ for $t \in (S, T]$? Since $\text{Im }W_r(0,T) = A(0,T)$, this shows an admissible control such that $x = \phi(T,0,0,\bar{u}) \Rightarrow x \in \text{Im }W_r(0,T)$, correct?