# Image of matrix $\int_0^t e^{sA}BB^T e^{sA^T} ds$

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

Let $A \in R^{n \times n}$ and $B \in R^{n \times m}$. Define

$$Q_t = \int_{0}^t e^{sA}BB^T e^{sA^T} ds$$

Suppose that $x \in \text{Im } Q_t$, ie, $\exists \eta \in R^n$ such that
$$x = Q_t \eta$$

Show that if $t_1 \geq t$, then $x$ is also on $\text{Im } Q_{t_1}$, ie,

$$\text{Im } Q_{t} \subseteq \text{Im } Q_{t_1}$$

My attempts can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422951/x-int-0s-es-sa-b-us-ds-rightarrow-x-int-0t-et-sa-b-barus). I didn't make much progress after that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M(s) = e^{sA}BB^Te^{sA^T}$. Note that $M(s)$ is (symmetric) positive semidefinite.  It follows that $Q_t = \int_0^tM(s)\,ds$ is positive semidefinite.

Noting that $\operatorname{Im}Q_t = \ker(Q_t)^\perp$, it suffices to show that $\ker Q_t \supseteq \ker Q_{t_1}$.  In order to do *that*, it suffices to note that
$$
Q_t x = 0 \iff\\
x^TQ_tx = 0 \iff\\
\int_0^t x^T M(s)x\,ds  = 0
$$
Note, however, that $f(s) = x^TM(s)x$ is a non-negative function.